# How to make query planner in PostgreSQL to start scanning partitions in descending order and skip scanning partitions if a value is found

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, partitioning

I have a table which I have partitioned on CreateDate, my typical query includes only shipping ID and seldom it contains a date range.

E.g -

```
select freight_weight, source_id, destination_id, shipping_id, create_date
from shipping_table
where shipping_id = 'AXP78076'
```

When I analyze this query, it starts from the earliest partition to latest partition, is there a way that it could be reversed, it should scan from latest partition till earliest partition, also if a value is found, it should stop scanning other partitions.

Is there any hint that I can pass in the query? or if there is some other way, please let me know.

More Information -

PostgreSQL 13.4

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.shipmentmaster_partitioned (
    "ShipmentMasterId" serial4 NOT NULL,
    "ShippingID" varchar(50) NULL,
    "CreatedDate" timestamp NULL,
    "CreatedBy" varchar(200) NULL,
    "OrderNo" varchar(50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "ShipmentMaster_partitioned_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ShipmentMasterId","CreatedDate")
) partition by range ("CreatedDate");


CREATE INDEX shipmentmaster_partitioned_createddate_idx ON dbo.shipmentmaster_partitioned USING btree ("CreatedDate");
CREATE INDEX lm_part_shippingid ON dbo.shipmentmaster_partitioned USING btree ("ShippingID" DESC NULLS LAST);
```

Created Partitions as below -

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2019m03 PARTITION OF dbo.shipmentmaster_partitioned
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2019-03-01') TO ('2019-04-01');
CREATE INDEX lm_part_shippingid_y2019m03 ON dbo.shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2019m03 USING btree ("ShippingID" DESC NULLS LAST);   

CREATE TABLE dbo.shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2019m04 PARTITION OF dbo.shipmentmaster_partitioned
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2019-04-01') TO ('2019-05-01');
CREATE INDEX lm_part_shippingid_y2019m04 ON dbo.shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2019m04 USING btree ("ShippingID" DESC NULLS LAST);
.
.
.
CREATE TABLE dbo.shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2021m12 PARTITION OF dbo.shipmentmaster_partitioned
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2021-12-01') TO ('2022-01-01');
CREATE INDEX lm_part_shippingid_y2021m12 ON dbo.shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2021m12 USING btree ("ShippingID" DESC NULLS LAST);
```

```
explain (analyze, buffers, format text) select * from dbo.shipmentmaster_partitioned sp 
where   "ShippingID" = 'S9169001008';



QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                             |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Append  (cost=0.15..265.03 rows=32 width=3808) (actual time=0.132..0.166 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                                               |
  Buffers: shared hit=62                                                                                                                                                               |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2019m05 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2019m05 lp_1  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=8887) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=0 loops=1)  |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=1                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2019m06 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2019m06 lp_2  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=9038) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)  |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=1                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2019m07 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2019m07 lp_3  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=7894) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)  |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2019m08 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2019m08 lp_4  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=6921) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)  |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2019m09 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2019m09 lp_5  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=4111) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)  |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2019m10 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2019m10 lp_6  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=3944) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)  |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2019m11 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2019m11 lp_7  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=3935) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)  |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2019m12 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2019m12 lp_8  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=2686) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)  |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2020m01 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2020m01 lp_9  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=2586) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)  |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2020m02 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2020m02 lp_10  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=2075) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2020m03 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2020m03 lp_11  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=2412) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2020m04 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2020m04 lp_12  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=2847) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2020m05 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2020m05 lp_13  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=2295) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2020m06 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2020m06 lp_14  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=3334) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2020m07 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2020m07 lp_15  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=2504) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2020m08 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2020m08 lp_16  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=3323) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2020m09 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2020m09 lp_17  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=2051) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2020m10 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2020m10 lp_18  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=3291) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2020m11 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2020m11 lp_19  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=2404) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2020m12 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2020m12 lp_20  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=2211) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2021m01 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2021m01 lp_21  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=2556) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2021m02 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2021m02 lp_22  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=2686) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2021m03 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2021m03 lp_23  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=2375) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2021m04 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2021m04 lp_24  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=2486) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2021m05 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2021m05 lp_25  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=2423) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=3                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2021m06 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2021m06 lp_26  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=2482) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2021m07 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2021m07 lp_27  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=2743) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2021m08 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2021m08 lp_28  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=3581) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2021m09 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2021m09 lp_29  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=3376) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2021m10 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2021m10 lp_30  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=2562) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2021m11 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2021m11 lp_31  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=2915) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1) |
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=1                                                                                                                                                          |
  ->  Index Scan using lm_part_shippingid_y2021m12 on shipmentmaster_partitioned_y2021m12 lp_32  (cost=0.12..8.14 rows=1 width=12933) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)|
        Index Cond: (("ShippingID")::text = 'S9169001008'::text)                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=2                                                                                                                                                          |
Planning:                                                                                                                                                                              |
  Buffers: shared hit=3                                                                                                                                                                |
Planning Time: 3.535 ms                                                                                                                                                                |
Execution Time: 0.531 ms                                                                                                                                                          |
```

Comment: @Ezio : "if a value is found, it should stop scanning other partitions". Do you mean you only want one row in the result ? If so you add `LIMIT 1` at the end of the query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have added the required information

Comment: @Ezio : have a look at the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITION-PRUNING)

Comment: Well, you are partitioning on a different column than you use in the `WHERE` clause. Obviously Postgres has to go through all partitions to find that value. It can't know that the value doesn't occur in any other partition (or that it can be found in the "latest" partition)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: true, I understand that, my question is if it can start scanning from latest partition and not from earliest partition, and I will put a limit 1 so that it doesnt scan other partitions.